# Not select a particular node child Elements in xslt using not

Tags: xslt, xpath

My XML is below. Is it possible to do this in same XSLT?

```
<response context="XXXX" type="abcd" errorCode="0" >
<output>
    <Applicants>
        <Applicant>
            <IndividualEmployments/>
            <Addresses/>
        </Applicant>
    </Applicants>
    <Assets>
        <Asset id="12345"></Asset>
    </Assets>
    <Liabilities>
        <Liability id="8765"></Liability>
    </Liabilities>
</output>
```

Desired output should be like below. I want two response nodes, one with *Assets* and the other with *Liabilities*.

```
<response context="XXXX" type="abcd" errorCode="0">
<output>
    <Applicants>
        <Applicant>
            <IndividualEmployments/>
            <Addresses/>
        </Applicant>
    </Applicants>
    <Assets>
    <Asset id="12345"></Asset>
</Assets>        
</output>
```

```
<response context="XXXX" type="abcd" errorCode="0">
<output>
    <Applicants>
        <Applicant>
            <IndividualEmployments/>
            <Addresses/>
        </Applicant>
    </Applicants>
    <Liabilities>
        <Liability id="8765"></Liability>
    </Liabilities>     
</output>
```

Comment: Which version of XSLT can you use? 1.0, 2.0 or 3.0?

Comment: What you show is not "two response node". It's two separate XML documents. To produce two or more separate outputs in a single XSL transformation, you need either a processor that supports XSLT 2.0, or an XSLT 1.0 processor that supports multiple outputs as an extension. -- If you really meant two nodes in the same document (which would be an XML fragment, without a single root element), that would be trivial even in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the `response` element and output it twice, making sure the content is different, for instance by passing a parameter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="response">
    <xsl:next-match>
      <xsl:with-param name="exclude" tunnel="yes" select="descendant::Liabilities"/>
    </xsl:next-match>
        <xsl:next-match>
      <xsl:with-param name="exclude" tunnel="yes" select="descendant::Assets"/>
    </xsl:next-match>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="output">
    <xsl:param name="exclude" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node() except $exclude"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If needed or wanted you can of course wrap each `xsl:next-match` I have in an `xsl:result-document`.